# Haskell foldl' not saving the space it was expected to

Tags: algorithm, haskell, memory, knapsack-problem

Trying to implement the straightforward dynamic programming algorithm for the Knapsack problem. Obviously this approach uses a lot of memory and so I am trying to optimize the memory utilized. I am simply trying to store only the previous row of my table in memory just long enough to compute the next row, and so on. At first I thought my implementation was solid, but it still ran out of memory as an implementation designed to store the whole table. So next I thought maybe I need `foldl'` instead of `foldr`, but it did not make any difference. My program continues to eat memory until my system runs out.

So I have 2 specific questions:

1. What is it about my code that is using up all the memory? I thought I was being clever by using a fold, because I assumed only the current value of the accumulator would be stored in memory.
2. What is the proper approach for achieving my goal; that is, storing only the most recent row in memory? I don't necessarily need code, maybe just some helpful functions and data types. More generally, what are some tips and techniques for understanding memory usage in Haskell?

Here is my implementation

```
data KSItem a = KSItem { ksItem :: a, ksValue :: Int, ksWeight :: Int} deriving (Eq, Show, Ord)
dynapack5 size items = finalR ! size
  where
    noItems = length items
    itemsArr = listArray(1,noItems) items
    row = listArray(1,size) (replicate size (0,[]))
    computeRow row item =
      let w = ksWeight item
          v = ksValue item
          idx = ksItem item
          pivot = let (lastVal, selections) = row ! w
                  in if v > lastVal 
                     then (v, [idx])
                     else (lastVal, selections)
          figure r c =
              if (prevVal + v) > lastVal
              then (prevVal + v, prevItems ++ [idx])
              else (lastVal, lastItems)
              where (lastVal, lastItems) = (r ! c)
                    (prevVal, prevItems) = (r ! (c - w))
          theRest = [ (figure row cw) | cw <- [(w+1)..size] ]
          newRow = (map (row!) [1..(w-1)]) ++ 
                   [pivot] ++
                   theRest
      in listArray (1,size) newRow
    finalR = foldl' computeRow row items
```

In my head, what I think this is doing is initializing the first row to (0,[])... repeated as necessary, then kicking off the fold where the next row is calculated based on the supplied row, and this value then becomes the accumulator. I'm not seeing where more and more memory is being consumed...

Random thought: what if i used the `\\` operator on the accumulator instead?

Comment: `foldl'` evaluates the accumulator to WHNF each step. But whether that's enough or not depends entirely on the value being stored in the accumulator. It seems to be an array of tuples of lots of stuff. These have to be normal boxed arrays, so forcing one to WHNF is going to ensure the array is allocated and each cell is initialized - to a pointer to a (probably unevaluated) thunk.

Comment: ok, so i think what you are saying is even though I am only working with one array in my code, in reality, every element of the array in every iteration of the fold will consume memory (which is exactly what I'm trying to avoid)? I guess that makes sense but I would have thought that the previous array would be GC'd because it would be no longer needed

Comment: also, now that i've read a little on WHNF, I think the issue with my code is the use of a list inside the tuple i'm using as my accumulator right? because that list wouldn't get evaluated to completion until i try to read from it outside of this function, so it would still need to store everything in memory "just in case" it ever needed to evaluate that list. Is my understanding of WHNF and laziness correct here?

Comment: Can you give some example input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Tom Ellis said, using `force` on the array solves the space issues. However, it is extremely slow, because `force` traverses all the lists in the array from start to end each time it is invoked. So we should only force as needed:

```
let res = listArray (1,size) newRow in force (map fst $ elems res) `seq` res
```

This fixes the space leak and it's also pretty fast.

If you want to take space efficiency to the logical next step, you could use bitsets of the indices of the items instead of lists of items. `Integers` are good for the job here since they automatically resize themselves to accommodate the highest set bit. Also, with `Integer`-s forcing is straightforward:

```
import qualified Data.Vector as V -- using this instead of Array cause I like it more
import Data.List
import Control.Arrow
import Data.Bits
import Control.DeepSeq

data KSItem a = KSItem { ksItem :: a, ksValue :: Int, ksWeight :: Int} deriving (Eq, Show, Ord)

dynapack5' :: Int -> [KSItem a] -> (Int, Integer)
dynapack5' size items = V.last solutions where
    items' = [KSItem i v w | (i, KSItem _ v w) <- zip [0..] items]

    solutions = foldl' add (V.replicate (size + 1) (0, 0::Integer)) items'

    add arr (KSItem item currVal w) = force $ V.imap go arr where
        go i (v, is) | w < i && v' > v = (v', is')
                     | otherwise       = (v, is)
            where (v', is') = (+currVal) *** (`setBit` item) $ arr V.! (i - w)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. The use of Control.Arrow (***) is something I would not have figured out on my own, but makes more sense to me seeing it implemented like this.

Comment: @parker.sikand also, another tip: you could sort the list of items in decreasing order of value density. This would give the heuristically best items the lowest indices, thereby reducing the size of the bitsets.

Answer (score 1):

`Data.Array` is non-strict in its elements so even though `foldl'` forces it to WHNF each time around the loop the contents don't get evaluated.  The simplest fix would be to import `Control.DeepSeq` and change

```
in listArray (1,size) newRow
```

to

```
in force (listArray (1,size) newRow)
```

This is doing more work than strictly necessary each time around the loop, but will do the job.

Unfortunately you can't just substitute unboxed arrays here, since your arrays contain a tuple containing a list.

Comment: this slowed the memory growth but did not stop it :( From what I understand, in theory, this answer is correct, but in my case, my algorithm was still using a lot of memory, I think it's due to the list i'm trying to accumulate. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: That's surprising.  It stopped the memory growth for me on some test data.  Are you sure it's not another part of your program that's causing the growth, or just the natural increase in the memory the `foldl'` contains as the lists get appended to?